# RHEL 6 default mount options - acl option missing

Tags: rhel, mount, acl

Two RHEL 6.8 servers. One test, one production. In theory derived from the same build channel in Satellite.

I spotted an issue on the production server when trying to add an ACL to a directory on an LV on a secondary volume group `/data`.
The ACL works perfectly on test server however when applying to the production server I get the following...

> setfacl: /data/dir1: Operation not supported

So `acl` option is probably not set for this mount point.

In `/etc/fstab` both are using `defaults`...

```
/dev/mapper/vg02-data   /data                   ext4    defaults        1 2
```

The output of `mount -l` is identical but the output of `tune2fs` differs...

```
testserver:root:~> mount -l | grep data
/dev/mapper/vg02-data on /data type ext4 (rw)

prodserver:root:~> mount -l | grep data
/dev/mapper/vg02-data on /data type ext4 (rw)

testserver:root:~> tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg02-data | grep options
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl

prodserver:root:~> tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg02-data | grep options
Default mount options:    (none)
```

Kernel version of both is `2.6.32-642.6.1.el6.x86_64`

I was under the impression that ACLs are enabled for `extX` file systems by default on RHEL and derivatives.
Where are these default options set?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:~# mount -o remount,acl /data
```

or

```
:~# for i in /dev/mapper/vg02-data ; do
umount $i
tune2fs -o acl $i
mount $i
done
```

and after that:

```
:~# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/vg02-data | grep options
```

You can also add rigidly to the **/etc/fstab**:

```
/dev/mapper/vg02-data   /data    ext4    acl,defaults    1 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of how to add the `acl` option. I'm just curious as to why one volume on one server has it in its `defaults` but another volume on another server doesn't. I would expect there to be OS-level consistency with this setting.

Comment: Check `cat /etc/mke2fs.conf | grep default
[defaults]
 default_mntopts = acl,user_xattr`

Comment: @Bahamut Great suggestion! Though files are identical on both servers and do not contain a `default_mntopts` section.